# How to move the view Y axis change when the keyboard appears

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

I am using the below functions, one which changes the Y axis whenever the keyboard appears the other function is one that if you tap anywhere on the view the keyboard disappears and the frame should go back to its original position.

I'm using firestore so when I launch the app I'm using firestore Auth to check if the user is logged in if the user is not logged in a login page is presented, once you have logged in the login page is dismissed and you are back to the root controller you are shown a tab with three tabs each tab connected to a separate view controller and each one is put into a navigation controller.

The first tab shows you to a view controller with a table view that shows all of my contacts,
I then tap on a cell which takes me to my message view controller where I can send and receive messages.

In my messages view controller in viewWillAppear i set the tab bar isHidden to true and then have my UITextView set to the bottom of the view controller

What's supposed to happen is once you tap the UITextView the UITextView should move up as the keyboard appears,

I use the same function, but what happens instead is that the keyboard appears and covers the UITextView,

then when I tap the main view to dismiss the keyboard the keyboard disappears but the frame then moves up but also it doesn't make sense how it's moving up to a certain distance because it doesn't move up to where it should've been then I was thinking that maybe it was moving up to the tab bar height but is not doing that it's somewhere in between

What's making it hard for me to understand is that I also tried that when you tap the contact cell instead of pushing the message view controller onto the navigation stack i used present, when i do this it works perfectly fine, but i would really like the message controller to be in the navigation stack so i can easily move back

Any feedback would be appreciated

```
    func keyboardNotifications() {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.
Note: `bottomConstraint` is the bottom constraint of the view containing the textview

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       . 
       . 
       .
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
        adjustingHeight(true, notification: notification)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
        adjustingHeight(false, notification: notification)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
        adjustingHeight(false, notification: notification)
    }
    
    func adjustingHeight(_ show:Bool, notification:Notification) {
        
        var userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let animationDurarion = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
        let changeInHeight = (keyboardFrame.height ) * (show ? 1 : 0)
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = changeInHeight
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDurarion, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```